# Maximum number of teams of fixed size over a score threshold

Tags: algorithms, combinatorial-optimization

I am wondering if there is any literature on the following combinatorial optimization problem:

- **Input**: $n, k, T\in \mathbb{N}$ and positive integers $s_1, \ldots, s_n$.

For intuition, we may think that $n$ represents a number of players; $k$ represents the number of players that form a team; $s_i$ represents the skill of player $i$ ($i=1,\ldots, n)$; and $T$ represents a desired minimum skill sum for the players in a team (see next).

- **Output**: The maximum integer $m$ such that it is possible to form $m$ teams (each of $k$ players) so that, for each team, the sum of the skills of the players in the team is at least $T$.

(Note: each player can be assigned only to at most one team)

At first glance I thought this is a variation of the [Bin Covering Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_covering_problem), but now I think that having a fixed number of objects (i.e. players) per bin (i.e. team) makes it quite different.

Comment: I take it each player is to be assigned to at most one team?

Comment: Yes, that's right! Edited the question

Comment: How big are $n$ and $k$? Are you able to share data for an explicit instance you are interested in solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming (ILP) as follows.  Let $I=\{1,\dots,n\}$ be the set of players, and let $J=\{1,\dots,\lfloor n/k \rfloor\}$ be the set of potential teams.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether player $i$ is on team $j$, and let binary decision variable $y_j$ indicate whether team $j$ is used.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{j\in J} y_j$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in J} x_{i,j} &\le 1 &&\text{for $i\in I$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{i\in I} x_{i,j} &= k y_j &&\text{for $j\in J$} \tag2 \\
\sum_{i\in I} s_i x_{i,j} &\ge T y_j &&\text{for $j\in J$} \tag3 \\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ assigns each player to at most one team.
Constraint $(2)$ assigns either $0$ or $k$ players to team $j$ according to the value of $y_j$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces the threshold if $y_j=1$.

One approach is to solve the problem directly with a generic ILP solver.  Another is to exploit symmetry with respect to $j$ and use column generation.  The latter approach is equivalent to relaxing $(2)$ and $(3)$ and applying Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition with identical blocks, as in the standard approach for the *cutting stock* problem.  In that case, each column corresponds to a team of $k$ players who together meet the threshold.  If the set of possible columns is small enough (for example, if $\binom{n}{k}$ is small enough), you can generate all columns a priori and solve a single *set packing* problem.

Comment: Very nice solution. Thanks!